# How to change the interval color on C3 Gauge in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, c3.js

I am trying to disply different colors for different intervals for the c3 Gauge. Specifically, I would like to display red, yellow and green for intervals.

```
library(c3)
data.frame(`Bullish Percent` = .50) %>% 
  c3() %>% 
  c3_gauge(max = 1, values = c(.3, .6, 1), threshold = list(unit = "value", max = 1))
```

I would expect this color to come out yellow but instead, the color is green.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is going on is that `values = c(.3, .6, 1)` should go inside `threshold = list()`.

The code below should work:

```
library(c3)
data.frame(`Bullish Percent` = .50) %>% 
  c3() %>% 
  c3_gauge(max = 1, threshold = list(unit = "value", max = 1,  values = c(.3, .6, 1)))
```

Result:

[image]

If we change `Bullish Percent` to .1, we get:

[image]